# MySQL and Bash explode results and reload to MySQL

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

I have a table currently in MySQL which looks like

```
id | parameters
1    gender=male;location=london;age=32
2    gender=female;location=manchester
3    speaks=french/english;gender=male
```

And i want to load this in to a table with 3 columns separating the parameters but keeping the id e.g. Any idea how i can do this and what methods could i use. Baring in mind that there are millions of rows so can't be too slow.
Thanks

```
id | key    | value
1    gender   male
1    location london
1    age      32
2    gender   female
2    location manchester
3    speaks   french/english
3    gender   male
```

Comment: good for normalizing... bad for suggesting doing it in bash. Use a proper language, and round-trip the data through that a script/program. it'll be far easier than trying to do this as a bash prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a small script to create an input csv feed file. Something along the lines like this -

```
awk '
BEGIN { 
    print "id,key,value"
}
NR>1 {    
    j=1
    split ($2, a, ";")
    for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) {
        split (a[i], b, "=")
        printf "%s,%s,%s\n",NR-1,b[j],b[j+1]
    }
}' file
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file
id | parameters
1    gender=male;location=london;age=32
2    gender=female;location=manchester
3    speaks=french/english;gender=male

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
BEGIN { 
    print "id,key,value"
}
NR>1 {    
    j=1
    split ($2, a, ";")
    for (i=1; i<=length(a); i++) {
        split (a[i], b, "=")
        printf "%s,%s,%s\n",NR-1,b[j],b[j+1]
    }
}' file
id,key,value
1,gender,male
1,location,london
1,age,32
2,gender,female
2,location,manchester
3,speaks,french/english
3,gender,male
```